# Dealing with infinite values in the same way as dealing with NA values for R programming

Tags: r, na, stat

I understand that R has many tools to deal with NA values. For example, na.omit, na.exclude, naresid and so on.

I was wondering if there are similar function like these to deal with "Inf" values as well.

For example,

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,Inf)

x.noInf <- *inf.exclude*(x) #will give 
        c(1,2,3,4)

 y = *infresid*(attr(x.noInf, "inf.action"), x-mean(x.noInf) ) #will give c(-1.5,-0.5,0.5,1.5,Inf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
x[is.finite(x)]
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Or

```
x[x!=Inf]
#[1] 1 2 3 4

x-mean(x[x!=Inf])
#[1] -1.5 -0.5  0.5  1.5  Inf
```

#### EDIT

If you have `Inf` and `-Inf`, `is.finite` would be a better option. In that case, you could also use,

```
 x[!x %in% c(Inf, -Inf)]
```